# ERROR 1064 (42000) Delete statement in RDS

Tags: mysql, rds

I tried to use RDS MySQL to store my data. This statement works in my local DB.

```
DELETE FROM movie_recommend mr WHERE mr.user_id = 71
```

But it's not executed in RDS MySQL.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mr where mr.user_id = 71' at line 1
```

[image: S]

Any helps what's wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Can you use table aliases in rds? If yes please provide a reference.

Comment: @P.Salmon Hi, as shown in the image. Aliases work in SELECT statement, but they don't work in DELETE statement. I use `DELETE FROM movie_recommend where user_id = 71` instead.

Comment: RDS does not support alias in delete then.